# Deploying an executable JAR on Azure functions without docker image?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am trying to replicate on Azure Functions the example that is in [Quickstart: Create a Go or Rust function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-other?tabs=go%2Clinux) in Java. I set up a couple of methods that respond to REST requests, and I bundled them as well as a Jetty server, that manages and routes the requests, into an executable Uber JAR. When I run `java -jar handler.jar`, an instance of a Jetty server is started, so I can navigate to `http://localhost:8080/ping`. I can achieve the same by using the JRE I have installed on my computer when using `func start` with the following `host.json`:

```
     "customHandler": {
         "description": {
           "defaultExecutablePath": "java",
           "arguments": ["-jar", "handler.jar"]
         },
         "enableForwardingHttpRequest": true
       }
```

Now, I'm trying to deploy this app to Azure Functions. One possible way would be to create a custom image with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/java:4-java11-slim
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot
COPY ["./functions", "/home/site/wwwroot"]
```

and start a function by using this image - I tried this and it works ok, but it seems to be quite inefficient to create a 1GB+ image, when the JAR I want to deploy takes up just a couple of MBs.

I was wondering, if there is a way to avoid this step? For example, push only the JAR and all the `.json` files to functions and use the default JRE, that is included when I create a Function App with the Java runtime stack? In other words, is it possible to achieve what I achieve locally when using `func start`, but use the JRE that is on azure instead?

The documentation (*"If your handler requires operating system or platform dependencies (such as a language runtime), you may need to use a custom container."*) is not that very clear about the topic.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Triggers and annotations paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java?tabs=bash%2Cconsumption#triggers-and-annotations) of the Azure Functions Java developer guide.

In the `function.json`, set the `scriptFile` field to the (relative) location of your jar, and set `entryPoint` to the location of the method the Azure Function should execute. Then using the [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools), you can do `func azure functionapp publish {function_app_name_in_Azure} --java` to publish too the Function App in the cloud.